# Aperio - to reveal?

Tags: meaning, conjugation

I’m trying to conjugate aperio to say, “I reveal/uncover/disclose”.  So, I guess I have two questions.  First, is aperio the correct verb to say this?  And, if so, what is the correct conjugation?

Answer (score 8):

*Aperiō* literally means to uncover something, to lay it bare. It can also be used for opening a door, restoring vision to blind eyes, explaining a concept to others, and so on.

A good way to find these meanings for an arbitrary word is to use [the Perseus word study tool](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph). Put in your word, choose "Latin", and submit. It should show all the possibilities on the left; when you've found the right one, click the "Lewis & Short" link to see a full dictionary entry for it.

Grammatically, you're in luck: the sample form given for a Latin verb (which usually ends in *-ō*) means "I do the thing". So *aperiō* literally means "I uncover".

Comment: Thanks!  That’s exactly the help I was looking for.  Again, thanks so much.

Comment: @Todd No problem! If this answered the question, remember you can "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left, under the arrows.

Answer (score 1):

This site should have some answers for you: http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?D1=9&T1=aperio

I believe it is conjugated as a normal 4th declension verb.

Comment: Welcome to the site, William! In case the link dies some day in the future, can you summarize the information in your answer? An answer should also be meaningful without following any external links.

Comment: Is that better?